# How to pipe while loop input to the encapsulated commands after the "do"

Tags: bash, curl, while-loop, pipe, stderr

My intention with the following is to grab (and then modify) cURL output when downloading a file.

```
    curl -# -L --user-agent 'Mozilla/5.0' -o "`echo -e "$filename"`" "$url" 2>&1 |
    while true
    do
        read <&1 line1 line2
        echo $line2
            if [ "`echo $line2 | grep -o "#"`" = "#" ] ; then
                echo "downloading..."
                break
            elif [ "`echo $line2 | grep -o "curl"`" = "curl" ] ; then
                echo $line2
                break
            else
            echo "stderr still empty"    
            fi
    done
```

The thing is that cURL output (which is sent to stderr) is dynamic, so I think I have to use a `while true` until something can be read, because if I immediately pipe through `while read` after `curl`, the pipe is empty.

Know I would like to send curl output directly to read input in the above construct.

AND I would really prefer not using any temp file (which could solve this very easily I agree :) )

EDIT : here is the curl dynamic curl output on stderr stored in a log :

```
 
######################################################################## 100.0%
                                                                           0.2%
                                                                           0.5%
                                                                           1.1%
#                                                                          1.6%
#                                                                          2.6%
##                                                                         3.3%
###                                                                        4.6%
####                                                                       6.1%
####                                                                       6.5%
####                                                                       6.8%
#####                                                                      7.3%
#####                                                                      7.7%
#####                                                                      8.0%
#####                                                                      8.2%
######                                                                     8.7%
```

Comment: ...but `read` should wait for the buffer to fill. I can pipe curl output directly to a `while read` loop no problem. Maybe you could post your errors?

Comment: [...and what you want achieve?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) (because grepping the curl's progressbar isn't the nicest idea...)

Comment: What I want to to is, first, check if download has correctly started of if curl return an error, and then (to simplify) print the progress bar in green or the error in red.

Comment: I have just realise something : at the end of each line of the log there is a ^M (CTRL-M)

Comment: I managed to convert them with `sed $'s/\r/\\\n/g'` or `tr '\r' '\n' < log > log2`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to report "downloading..." while curl is downloading, you might want to do something like this (note - somewhat advanced bash hacking):

```
curl "$url" -o "$outfile" -vs > >( # redirect stdout to sub-shell, note the space
  # parse curl's "verbose" output which tells us what is happening
  # while we use -s to silence the standard progress bar which is useless for this
  while read line; do # read verbose progress messages
    if grep -q "Connected" <<<"$line"; then # wait for curl to connect
      echo "Downloading..."
      break
    fi
  done
  cat > /dev/null # make sure to consume all stdin if we break early, to prevent "broken pipe"
) 2>&1 || echo "Error!"
```

The reason I used a process substitution to direct output to a subshell, is to not lose the curl exit code which will be non-zero if there was an error, allowing me to use bash logical evaluation to report the error (or I could just capture it from `$?` and examine it - curl has very detailed exit code reporting, so I can figure out what went wrong from the exit code. Consult `man curl` for details).

Also note the location of `2>&1` which redirects the standard error stream to the standard output stream so the process substitution can grab the curl progress messages that are normally posted to the error stream. This redirection must come after the stdout capture because otherwise it will just create a duplicate of stdout and the subshell will get nothing. This is explained better in the Bash manual section about stream duplication.

### Notes about your code

You have several issues in the above code:

*) Instead of

```
... -o "`echo $filename`" ...
```

you should just do

```
... -o "$filename" ...
```

There's really no reason for the additional indirection when all you want to do is for bash to expand `$filename` as the value of the `-o` argument.

*) This makes no sense:

```
read <&1
```

The file descriptor `1` is the standard output - you really don't want to read from that. If you want to read from the standard input, there's nothing to redirect from - `read` by default reads from standard input.

*) This is not good practice:

```
if [ "`echo $var | grep -o "value"`" == "value" ]; then
```

for many reasons - first thing, `grep -o` is almost practically useless, especially with simple text searches, because it will just output what you wanted to find or not (depending if the value was found) which maps exactly to the `grep` exit code being 0 or 1. So instead its better to simply do `if echo $var | grep -q "value"; then`. This expression will succeeds if `grep` succeeded and will fail otherwise. `-q` is used to silence the output because you don't need it (just if it succeeded or not). Also if you have the text in a variable, using `echo` to get it to `grep` is just annoying (it opens a sub-shell and forks and stuff), instead say `grep -q "value" <<<"$var"`.

Lastly, regarding reporting if `curl` is downloading or not, I personally think that the `curl` progress indicator is good enough, but if its not then just silence it with `-s`.

Comment: thanks @Guss, it is a very instructive answer ! your last part of code could do the trick, yes, but I don't like the `sleep 1`, since this construct might not work properly if the internet connection is a bit slow... That's why I am intending to grab the output. I don't know why but when I pipe the curl output to tr or sed, the output is always empty ! Do you have any idea about that ?

Comment: I forgot to mention the main reason your code won't work - the curl progress notifications are sent on the standard error stream (file descriptor 2), so a pipe that is connected to standard output will not see the progress messages.

Comment: Yes, that's right, but I do have duplicated fd 2 on 1 for my curl command !

Comment: please see my updated answer - I think it has everything you need.

Comment: whao I will need a while to process and test all that, but it seems pretty good, many thanks Guss :)
I was precisely thinking of using the -v and -s options to grab the output and make the test from it. But why I can't pipe properly the output when the progress bar is on ? that's still a mystery...

Comment: They progress bar is meant for console and has console control chars that don't work well when piping. It's best to not try to parse such ui elements.